# subprocess.run gives me error "UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)" python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I wrote a script in python3.9 and used subprocess.run to run shell scripts from inside the python, As a requirement, I needed to downgrade to **python3.6**, and some of the code needed to change.

What hasn't changed is the way I run the sub processes but for some reason, I now get an error like:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The line that failed is, I tried to add ***"encoding='utf_8' "*** from what I read but it didn't help:

```
smc_shell_script = subprocess.run(['sh','smc.sh'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, universal_newlines=True, encoding='utf_8')
```

When I reuse this code and run other commands some of them are working and some are not which is probably a result of the command output that I am running.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out,
In the end, I used The errors parameter which is described in the linked documentation for [io.TextIOWrapper:](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper)

`'backslashreplace'` causes malformed data to be replaced by a backslashed escape sequence.

So My code looks like that now:

```
smc_shell_script = subprocess.run(['sh', 'smc.sh'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, universal_newlines=True, errors='backslashreplace')
```